# ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

This is my code:

```
import sqlite3
connector = sqlite3.connect("Database_tester.db")
cursor = connector.cursor()
def Table_making():
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tester(Roll_numbers TEXT, Names TEXT)")
def data_entry():
    data = ((i,) for i in range(1, 11))
    inputy = ((input(x),) for x in range(1,11))
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO Tester (Roll_numbers, Names) VALUES (?, ?)", (data, inputy))
    connector.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connector.close()
Table_making()
data_entry()
```

My code is continuously giving me this error:

```
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

I have no idea how this error is occurring and I want to know a way of fixing it.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany. I think you might need to `zip` your two generators together to produce the *pairs* of values that you want here?

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the documentation at https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html that the second parameter in `cursor.executemany()` is a list of tuples where each tuple is one row. You seem to be passing in a tuple of tuples where each of the inner tuple is a column. Using `zip` as Tom mentioned above should fix it.

Comment: Using the zip doesn't fix the error, but it gives a new error:                                  sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 1 supplied.

Comment: Did you make sure you are actually passing in a list of tuples where each tuple is one row?  

    `data = tuple(range(1, 11))

    inputy = (input(x) for x in range(1,11))

    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO Tester (Roll_numbers, Names) VALUES (?, ?)", zip(data, inputy))`